# Nested switch: Outer switch automatically executes the second case after exiting inner switch

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a menu for my RPG-esque program, it consists of the Main Menu(outer switch) and Inventory Menu(inner switch), my problem is when I exit from my inner switch, the next case of the outer switch(dispChar()) executes. 
Here is the code

```
do{
printf("\n(i)Open Inventory\t(c)View Character\t(p)[Mini-Game]Hit the Chest!\t(z)Exit\n");
mainMenu = getch();
switch (mainMenu)
{
    case 'i':
        OpenInventory(&inv);
        do
        {
        printf("\n(a)Equip Weapon\t(b)Equip Helmet\t(c)Equip Suit\t(d)Equip Gloves\t(e)Equip Boots\t(z)Back\n");
        op2 = getch();
        switch(op2)
        {
            case 'a':
                equipWep(&chara, &inv);
                break;
            case 'b':
                equipHelm(&chara, &inv);
                break;
            case 'c':
                equipSuit(&chara, &inv);
                break;
            case 'd':
                equipGloves(&chara, &inv);
                break;
            case 'e':   
                equipBoots(&chara, &inv);
                break;
        }
        }while(op2 != 'z');
    case 'c':
        dispChar(chara);
        break;
    case 'p':
        if(chara.wep.damage == 0)
        {
            printf("No weapon equiped!");
        }else
        {
            grind(&chara);
            break;
        }


}
}while(mainMenu != 'z');
```

Here are some of my functions:

```
void OpenInventory(inventory inv[size])
{
    dispWep(inv);
    dispHelm(inv);
    dispSuit(inv);
    dispGloves(inv);
    dispBoots(inv);
}

void dispChar(character chara)
{
    printf("\nName:%s\nSex:%c\nWeapon:%s\nHelmet:%s\nSuit:%s\nGloves:%s\nBoots:%s\n",chara.charName, chara.charGen, chara.wep.weaponName,chara.helm,chara.sut,chara.glabs,chara.buts);  
}
```

If the rest of my code is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the outer `switch` statement to continue to execute rest of the cases, add a `break;` after the end of the inner `switch` and before the next `case` statement of the outer `switch` statement.

```
switch (mainMenu)
{
    case 'i':
        OpenInventory(&inv);
        do
        {
           printf("\n(a)Equip Weapon\t(b)Equip Helmet\t(c)Equip Suit\t(d)Equip Gloves\t(e)Equip Boots\t(z)Back\n");
           op2 = getch();
           switch(op2)
           {
              ...
           }
        } while(op2 != 'z');

        // Add this
        break;

    case 'c':
```